# Basic table creation

Tags: tables

I'm having problems creating a basic table. I'm using an R package to produce LaTeX output. This is what it gives me:

```
\begin{tabular}{rlrrr}
\hline
Disorder & Correlation & StDev & N \\ 
\hline
GAD & 0.31 & 0.16 &  48 \\ 
OCD & 0.40 & 0.20 & 126 \\ 
SAD & 0.26 & 0.13 &  81 \\ 
PTSD & 0.35 & 0.16 & 175 \\ 
Agoraphobia & 0.25 & 0.16 &  21 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I'm sure there are various errors here--any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are after here: the table should compile OK.

Comment: "I'm sure there are various errors here". Do you have specifics? Because - as Joseph mentioned - the table compiles just fine.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). As per the other comments, the table you posted works great.  For future reference I would recommend using [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs).  Also, it would be helpful if you posted the "errror" messages, as I suspect they are not related to this table.

Comment: The error reads: "LaTeX Error: Environment table undefined." Might this have something to do with my install?

Comment: Well you need to add `\documentclass{article} \begin{document}`  at the start and `\end{document}` at the end to get a complete compilable document.  Or whatever `\documentclass` you are using.

Comment: Of course. Thank you! It's working properly now.

Comment: Also, you define 5 columns and only use 4. It's not an error, but unnecessary. You can just write `\begin{tabular}{rlrr}` instead of `{rlrrr}`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been resolved in the comments